# wrong number of arguments (3 for 1) after upgrading rails from 3.1.1 to 3.1.3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I have upgraded my rails 3.1.1 application to rails 3.1.3, and now, on every request, it answers only `wrong number of arguments (3 for 1)`. Unfortunately, it doesn't says where the error was, and application trace is empty. I think there's some compatibility problem, but I really don't know where to dig.

There are my Gemfile and a framework trace: https://gist.github.com/1519479

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Looks like one of middlewares used in your app accepts only one argument but is called with tree of them for some reason. Unfortunately, without one more line of stacktrace that most likely should be between `wrong number of arguments` and `rack (1.3.5) lib/rack/builder.rb:78:in 'new'` it'd be difficult to find the problem.

Comment: it will be much easier if you can identify the differences in Gemfile.lock which contains all the gem versions, before and after the upgrade

Comment: Run `bundle show` and check version of `omniauth` gem. May be while upgrading rails you updated `omniauth` as well. Version 1.* requires separate gem `omniauth-twitter` for twitter authentication. As you don't have it in your `Gemfile` it tries to load as middleware `Twitter` class from `twitter` gem that would cause similar error.

Comment: @KL-7 you're absolutely right! Please, post your comment as an answer. Thank you very much.

Comment: Done. Small advice: when you have some configuration issues with a open-source project hosted on Github you'd better give a link to it right away. Having full project at hands helps a lot in cases like that =)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Run `bundle show` and check version of omniauth gem. May be while upgrading rails you updated `omniauth` as well.

Version `1.*` of `omniauth` requires separate gem `omniauth-twitter` for twitter authentication. As you don't have it in your `Gemfile` it tries to load as middleware `Twitter` class from `twitter` gem that would cause similar error.

To avoid issues like that in the future consider using `"~> 0.2.6"` for gems versioning instead of `">= 0.2.6"`. It protects you from unexpected major releases of gems you're using.