# wrong number of arguments (3 for 2) after upgrading from Rails 3.0.14 to Rails 3.1.4

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1

Everything was working fine in Rails 3.0.14, but after changing 
`gem 'rails', '3.0.14'` to `gem 'rails', '3.1.4'` and running `bundle update rails` I now get the following error:

````
Started GET "/" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-03-16 11:11:44 -0400
  Processing by PagesController#index as HTML
  Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 54ms
  ArgumentError (wrong number of arguments (3 for 2)):
     app/controllers/application_controller.rb:37:in `customize_by_subdomain'```
````

The most popular answer seemed to be that sqlite3 needed to be updated, but I did `bundle update sqlite3` and I still have the same problem.

Here is the full trace: https://gist.github.com/2050530

The method that it is complaining about looks like this:

```
35 def customize_by_subdomain
36   subdomain = (request.subdomain.present? && request.subdomain != 'www' && request.subdomain) || 'launch'
37   @current_org = Organization.find_by_subdomain(subdomain) || Organization.find_by_subdomain('launch')
38 end
```

I have looked at the multitude of similar questions and I not found anything that solves my problem. The closest was question to mine was: [wrong number of arguments (3 for 1) after upgrading rails from 3.1.1 to 3.1.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8630441/wrong-number-of-arguments-3-for-1-after-upgrading-rails-from-3-1-1-to-3-1-3) but I am using authlogic and the version I am using didn't change after upgrading rails.

The only other interesting thing is my entire test suite passes, except for one request/integration spec which goes through the process of creating a new user. It seems strange that my request specs work fine when I can't even access a page in development.

Any ideas on what I can do to get to the bottom of this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like your New Relic plugin may need to be updated to a new version. In your stacktrace, the first line is from the New Relic code in your plugins folder. From their site, it looks like they released new Rails 3.1-specific code:

http://blog.newrelic.com/2011/07/29/for-the-active-record-new-relic-support-for-rails-3-1-is-here/

In the blog post, they talk about changes to the way ActiveRecord does logging, and your exception was triggered on the log_with_instrumentation method.

It looks like now you should install it as a gem rather than a plugin:
https://github.com/newrelic/rpm

Hope this helps.

Comment: nice work picking up on that. Taking out the new-relic plugin fixes everything