# ArgumentError in AuthenticationsController - wrong number of arguments (3 for 1)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, omniauth

I'm trying to get users to successfully log in using a provider but I'm getting this error. The user is getting **created successfully** but this error message prevents the user from getting to the signed in page

```
wrong number of arguments (3 for 1)
    app/helpers/sessions_helper.rb:4:in `sign_in'
    app/controllers/authentications_controller.rb:12:in `create'
```

Here's the relevant portion of the sessions_helper

```
 module SessionsHelper


  def sign_in(user)
    cookies.permanent[:remember_token] = user.remember_token
    current_user = user
  end

  def sign_in_and_redirect(user)
    redirect_to root_path
  end

  def signed_in?
    !current_user.nil?
  end

  def current_user=(user)
    @current_user = user
  end

  def current_user
    @current_user ||= User.find_by_remember_token(cookies[:remember_token])
  end

  def current_user?(user)
    user == current_user
  end

  def sign_out
    current_user = nil
    cookies.delete(:remember_token)
  end

  def store_location
    session[:return_to] = request.fullpath
  end

  def redirect_back_or(default)
    redirect_to(session[:return_to] || default)
    session.delete(:return_to)
  end

  def signed_in_user
    unless signed_in?
      store_location
      redirect_to signin_path, notice: "Please sign in." 
    end
  end
end
```

Here's the authentications controller

```
  class AuthenticationsController < InheritedResources::Base

def index
    @authentications = current_user.authentications if current_user
end

    def create
  omniauth = request.env['omniauth.auth']
  authentication = Authentication.find_by_provider_and_uid(omniauth['provider'], omniauth['uid'])
  if authentication
     flash[:notice] = "Signed in successfully"
     sign_in_and_redirect(:user, authentication.user)
  elsif current_user
   token = omniauth['credentials'].token
   secret = omniauth['credentials'].token
   current_user.authentications.create!(:provider => omniauth['provider'], :uid => omniauth['uid'], :token => token, :secret => token_secret)
   flash[:notice] = "Authentication successful"
   redirect_to authentications_url
   else
    user = User.new
    user.apply_omniauth(omniauth)
    if user.save!
    flash[:notice] = "Signed in successfully"
     sign_in(:user, authentication.user)
   else
    session[:omniauth] = omniauth.except('extra')
    redirect_to '/signup'
   end
end
end

def destroy
    @authentication = current_user.authentications.find(params[:id])
    @authentication.destroy
    flash[:notice] = "Successfully destroyed authentication"
    redirect_to authentications_url

end
end
```

and finally here's the user model

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation
  has_secure_password
  has_many :authentications
 before_validation :no_password_omniauth
 validates :password, length: { minimum: 6 }
 validates :password_confirmation, presence: true
 @called_omniauth = false

 def apply_omniauth(omniauth)
 authentications.build(:provider => omniauth['provider'],
 :uid => omniauth['uid'],
 :token => omniauth['credentials'].token,
 :secret => omniauth['credentials'].secret)
 @called_omniauth = true
 self.email = "test@example.com"
 self.name = omniauth['info']['name']
 self.password = self.password_confirmation = "password"
 end

     def password_required
    return false if @called_omniauth == true
    (authentications.empty? || !password.blank?)
end


  def twitter
  unless @twitter_user
  provider = self.authentications.find_by_provider('twitter')
  @twitter_user = Twitter::Client.new(:oauth_token => provider.token, :oauth_token_secret => provider.secret) rescue nil
  end
  @twitter_user
  end



    private

       def apply_twitter(omniauth)
       if (extra = omniauth['extra']['user_hash'] rescue false)
       end
    end

       def no_password_omniauth
       self.password_digest = SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64 unless password_required
       end
    end
```

Full trace

```
app/helpers/sessions_helper.rb:9:in `sign_in_and_redirect'
app/controllers/authentications_controller.rb:12:in `create'
actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:4:in `send_action'
actionpack (3.2.3) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:167:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:10:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.2.3) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:18:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (3.2.3) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:425:in `_run__489817761__process_action__312945192__callbacks'
activesupport (3.2.3) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `__run_callback'
activesupport (3.2.3) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in `_run_process_action_callbacks'
activesupport (3.2.3) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (3.2.3) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:17:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:29:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (3.2.3) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:123:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (3.2.3) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
activesupport (3.2.3) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:123:in `instrument'
actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:29:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:205:in `process_action'
activerecord (3.2.3) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:18:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.2.3) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:121:in `process'
actionpack (3.2.3) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:45:in `process'
actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:203:in `dispatch'
actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:14:in `dispatch'
actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:246:in `block in action'
actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:73:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:73:in `dispatch'
actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:36:in `call'
journey (1.0.4) lib/journey/router.rb:68:in `block in call'
journey (1.0.4) lib/journey/router.rb:56:in `each'
journey (1.0.4) lib/journey/router.rb:56:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:600:in `call'
omniauth (1.1.4) lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:401:in `call_app!'
omniauth (1.1.4) lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:363:in `callback_phase'
omniauth-oauth (1.0.1) lib/omniauth/strategies/oauth.rb:58:in `callback_phase'
omniauth (1.1.4) lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:226:in `callback_call'
omniauth (1.1.4) lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:182:in `call!'
omniauth (1.1.4) lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:164:in `call'
omniauth (1.1.4) lib/omniauth/builder.rb:49:in `call'
warden (1.2.1) lib/warden/manager.rb:35:in `block in call'
warden (1.2.1) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `catch'
warden (1.2.1) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/best_standards_support.rb:17:in `call'
rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/etag.rb:23:in `call'
rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:25:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/head.rb:14:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:21:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:242:in `call'
rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:210:in `context'
rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:205:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:338:in `call'
activerecord (3.2.3) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:64:in `call'
activerecord (3.2.3) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:467:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:28:in `block in call'
activesupport (3.2.3) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `_run__1022619158__call__651148843__callbacks'
activesupport (3.2.3) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `__run_callback'
activesupport (3.2.3) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in `_run_call_callbacks'
activesupport (3.2.3) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:65:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:31:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:16:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:56:in `call'
railties (3.2.3) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:26:in `call_app'
railties (3.2.3) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:16:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:22:in `call'
rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
activesupport (3.2.3) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:72:in `call'
rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/lock.rb:15:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:62:in `call'
railties (3.2.3) lib/rails/engine.rb:479:in `call'
railties (3.2.3) lib/rails/application.rb:220:in `call'
rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
railties (3.2.3) lib/rails/rack/log_tailer.rb:14:in `call'
rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:59:in `service'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/server.rb:191:in `block in start_thread'
```

How can I resolve this error? Thanks in advance

SessionsController

```
 def create
    user = User.find_by_email(params[:session][:email])
    if user && user.authenticate(params[:session][:password])
      sign_in user
      redirect_to root_url
    else
      flash.now[:error] = "Invalid email/password combination"
      render 'new'
    end
  end
```

And the UsersController

```
 def create
    @user = User.new(params[:user])
    if @user.save
      sign_in @user
      flash[:success] = "Welcome"
      redirect_to root_url
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  def edit
  end

  def update
    if @user.update_attributes(params[:user])
      sign_in @user
      flash[:success] = "Profile updated"
      redirect_to @user
    else
      render 'edit'
    end
  end
```

Comment: can you post your `sign_in_and_redirect` method?

Comment: not sure if I wrote the code above correctly.. but here's the `sign_in_and_redirect` method inside `sessions_helper.rb`.  ---------`def sign_in_and_redirect(user)
    redirect_to root_path
  end`

Comment: that's weird, but how's about calling `sign_in_and_redirect(:user)` instead of `sign_in_and_redirect(:user, authentication.user)` in your create action?

Comment: I get an argumenterror `wrong number of arguments (2 for 1)` that references the create action and the `sign_in_and_redirect` method

Comment: i don't know, you still haven't provided the code where you call the `sign_in` method

Comment: oh, for authentication using omniauth, I don't call the sign_in method. The original argumentment error referenced it so I posted it. I updated the original post and that's full code for the `AuthenticationsController` and majority of the user.rb. Do you need to see anything else?

Comment: the user is getting created except they get stuck from reaching the root_path due to this error message.. any ideas?

Comment: so change it back to what it was like `sign_in_and_redirect(:user, authentication.user)` if it's throwing a new error like that

Comment: if I change it back to my original code, I still get the argument error `wrong number of arguments (3 for 1)`. I posted up more detail in the original post. Does the rest of my code look okay?

Comment: i still don't see where you are calling the `sign_in` method

Comment: ok I just posted the SessionsController; please check the very bottom of my original post

Comment: still would suggest to turn back to the 'older' problem since now its two problems and back then was one problem

Comment: ok I updated everything back to the older problem and updated the original post

Comment: Please run bundle show and check version of omniauth gem

Comment: version of omniauth gem is 1.1.4, version of omniauth-twitter is 0.0.16, version of omniauth-oauth is 1.0.1

Comment: try to install omniauth "~> 0.2.6". Check this here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8630441/wrong-number-of-arguments-3-for-1-after-upgrading-rails-from-3-1-1-to-3-1-3

Comment: I uninstalled omniauth 1.1.4 and tried to install 0.2.6 but it gave me this error "The bundle currently has omniauth locked at 1.1.4." Then I ran `bundle update omniauth` to see the reason for this message, and I got "oa-more (=0.2.6) ruby depends on multi_json (~) 1.0.0) ruby, and uglifier (=1.2.3) depends on multi-json (1.6.1)

Comment: try to post it as a different question with gems added, i'm sorry, don't know the source of the problem

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue doing the tuturial.  Have you tried sign_in_and_redirect(user: authentication.user)?