# ArgumentError, wrong number of arguments (3 for 1) in create action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm using the omniauth gem to allow users to signup/login to my rails app

Here's a part of my gemfile

```
gem 'omniauth'
gem 'omniauth-twitter'
gem 'twitter'
```

Omniauth =is v1.1.4, 
Omniauth-twtter is v0.0.16, 
Omniauth-oauth is v1.0.1,
Twitter is 4.6.2

I came across this thread with a similar error [wrong number of arguments (3 for 1) after upgrading rails from 3.1.1 to 3.1.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8630441/wrong-number-of-arguments-3-for-1-after-upgrading-rails-from-3-1-1-to-3-1-3) so I tried to uninstall Omniauth and downgrade to version "~> 0.2.6" but I got this message:

The bundle currently has omniauth locked at 1.1.4. 
Is the omniauth version the cause of the issue or something else?

The error message that I'm trying to fix is this when I try to use Twitter signin

```
ArgumentError in AuthenticationsController#create
wrong number of arguments (3 for 1)

app/helpers/sessions_helper.rb:4:in `sign_in'
app/controllers/authentications_controller.rb:12:in `create'
```

Here's my authentications_controller.rb

```
class AuthenticationsController < InheritedResources::Base

def index
    @authentications = current_user.authentications if current_user
end

def create
  omniauth = request.env['omniauth.auth']
  authentication = Authentication.find_by_provider_and_uid(omniauth['provider'], omniauth['uid'])
  if authentication
     flash[:notice] = "Signed in successfully"
     sign_in_and_redirect(:user, authentication.user)
  elsif current_user
   token = omniauth['credentials'].token
   secret = omniauth['credentials'].token
   current_user.authentications.create!(:provider => omniauth['provider'], :uid => omniauth['uid'], :token => token, :secret => token_secret)
   flash[:notice] = "Authentication successful"
   redirect_to authentications_url
   else
    user = User.new
    user.apply_omniauth(omniauth)
    if user.save!
    flash[:notice] = "Signed in successfully"
     sign_in(:user, authentication.user)
   else
    session[:omniauth] = omniauth.except('extra')
    redirect_to '/signup'
   end
end
end

def destroy
    @authentication = current_user.authentications.find(params[:id])
    @authentication.destroy
    flash[:notice] = "Successfully destroyed authentication"
    redirect_to authentications_url

end
end
```

Here's my sessions_helper.rb

```
module SessionsHelper

  def sign_in(user)
    cookies.permanent[:remember_token] = user.remember_token
    current_user = user
  end

  def sign_in_and_redirect(user)
    redirect_to root_path
  end
```

Here's my sessions_controller.rb

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController
  def create
    user = User.find_by_email(params[:session][:email])
    if user && user.authenticate(params[:session][:password])
      sign_in user
      redirect_to root_url
    else
      flash.now[:error] = "Invalid email/password combination"
      render 'new'
    end
  end
```

Here's the user.rb model

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation
  has_secure_password
  has_many :authentications

  before_save { |user| user.email = user.email.downcase }
  before_save :create_remember_token
  before_validation :no_password_omniauth
  validates_uniqueness_of :name, { case_sensitive: false }
  validates :name,  presence: true, length: { maximum: 50 }
  VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-.]+\.[a-z]+\z/i
  validates :email, presence: true, format: { with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX },
                    uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }
  validates :password, length: { minimum: 6 }
  validates :password_confirmation, presence: true

  @called_omniauth = false

  def apply_omniauth(omniauth)
 authentications.build(:provider => omniauth['provider'],
 :uid => omniauth['uid'],
 :token => omniauth['credentials'].token,
 :secret => omniauth['credentials'].secret)
 @called_omniauth = true
 self.email = "test@example.com"
 self.name = omniauth['info']['name']
 self.password = self.password_confirmation = "password"
 end

  def password_required
    return false if @called_omniauth == true
    (authentications.empty? || !password.blank?)
end


  def twitter
unless @twitter_user
provider = self.authentications.find_by_provider('twitter')
@twitter_user = Twitter::Client.new(:oauth_token => provider.token, :oauth_token_secret => provider.secret) rescue nil
end
@twitter_user
end


  private

    def create_remember_token
      self.remember_token = SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64
    end

    def apply_twitter(omniauth)
if (extra = omniauth['extra']['user_hash'] rescue false)
# Example fetching extra data. Needs migration to User model:
# self.firstname = (extra['name'] rescue '')
end
end

def no_password_omniauth
  self.password_digest = SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64 unless password_required
end


def hash_from_omniauth(omniauth)
{
:provider => omniauth['provider'],
:uid => omniauth['uid'],
:token => omniauth['credentials']['token'],
:secret => omniauth['credentials']['secret']
}
end
end
```

Finally, here's the users_controller.rb

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :signed_in_user,
                only: [:index, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_filter :correct_user,   only: [:edit, :update]
  before_filter :admin_user,     only: :destroy

def create
    @user = User.new(params[:user])
    if @user.save
      sign_in @user
      flash[:success] = "Welcome"
      redirect_to root_url
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  def edit
  end
```

Comment: The error message is clear. You are trying to pass 3 arguments where it expects one.

Comment: how do I fix this? I've been stuck at this step for a while now so any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You've defined sign_in_and_redirect to accept only one argument - but you're passing two arguments in.

So perhaps `sign_in_and_redirect(:user, authentication.user)` in your controller should become `sign_in_and_redirect(authentication.user)`.

But it's worth noting two things:

- Your sign_in_and_redirect method doesn't actually sign the user in, it just redirects them.
- If you're using Devise, then you'll have a method with that name already defined with the following signature: `sign_in_and_redirect(resource_or_scope, *args)`. I would recommend either using their method (if you're using Devise with OmniAuth) or naming your method something else to avoid conflicts and confusion.

[Actually, my analysis may be a little off, given the stack trace points to your sign_in method, not sign_in_and_redirect - are the line numbers in the stack trace accurate for the code you've shared, or have you removed some code?]

Comment: hey pat, I noticed that by changing the code in the controller to `sign_in_and_redirect(authentication.user)` does make the argument disappear and it routes the user to just the homepage (not getting signed in). Do you know why their accounts are not being created though? it was working before so not sure what changed

Comment: Are they not being created? Or just not being signed in?

Comment: They're getting created again, but now I'm getting this error message: `undefined method user' for nil:NilClass`. This is from the line `sign_in(authentication.user)` inside def create in the authentications_controller. Where should the method "user" be defined correctly?

Comment: I'm not sure - can you update the code files in your question to match their current state?

Comment: I'm at the final step... and I'm trying to actually sign in the user. You were right that it just redirects them. If I am not using devise, how should the `sign_in_and_redirect` be defined and where? this would really help me out a lot so please let me know

Comment: call `sign_in user` within your `sign_in_and_redirect` method.